# jquery add class but chrome doesn‘t render

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

css code

```
#id .class1 .class2 .a{max-height:20px}
.b{max-height:100px}
```

I use jquery add a class 'b' to the element which has class 'a',but chrome doesn't render it.
but if I write

```
#id .class1 .class2 .b{max-height:100px}
```

chrome will render it...

I just want know why

Comment: What is your jQuery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
.b{max-height:100px !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of [css rule priority](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html)

Ex:

```
<div id="id">
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2">
            <div class="a">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above case if a class `b` is added to `div.a`, then the rule `#id .class1 .class2 .a` will override rule `.b` because it is more specific

The cascade works like this:

1. The more important rule applies.
2. If equally important, the more specific rule applies.
3. If equally specific, the latter rule applies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your CSS selector has a higher degree of specificity, which means it will take precedence over the jQuery selector with a single class. When selecting the element with jQuery, try using the same full path you have in your CSS.

```
$('#id .class1 .class2 .a').addClass...
```